# How to trigger method in a view from other view

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two different views. In first view, I am listening for an event, whenever I receive the event I want to trigger a method in different view. Is this achievable? How can this be achieved, do I need to use a stream for this? I am using provider to share data and usually I access it like
`context.read<Item>().doSomething`

```dart
class View1 {
  final Location _location = Location();
  
  _location.onLocationChanged.listen((event){ 
     print(event); // After receiving the event, I want to trigger the method in view2
   }

}
```

```dart
class View2 {
 void method() {
   print('I want to be called when event is received from view1')
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to explore the [Observer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) programming pattern.